# Compact operator $T_{A,B}$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ where $X$ is a Banach space. Define $T_{A,B}: \mathcal{B}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(X)$ by $T_{A,B}(S)=ASB$.

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are compact then $T_{A,B}$ is compact.

I consider a bounded sequence $\{S_n\}$ in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ but I can't find a subsequence of $T_{A,B}(S_n)$ such that is convergent. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ is compact the image of the unit ball under $B$ is pre-compact, in  particular separable. Let $x_m$ be a countable dense subset of this image. Now consider for $m$ fixed the sequence $(S_n x_m)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, since $A$ is compact you have a sub-sequence so that $A S_{n_{k}}x_m$ converges. By the diagonal argument you may assume that $n_k$ is so that $AS_{n_k}x_m$ converges for *every* $m$.

Denote with $A\!S$ the map $\{x_m\mid m\in\Bbb N\}\to X$ given by $x_m\mapsto \lim_k A S_{n_k}x_m$. Since $S_n$ is bounded you have that
$$\|A\!S(x_m) -A\!S(x_l)\| ≤ \sup_n\|AS_n\|\,\|x_m-x_l\|$$
and the map is **Lipschitz**. You may then extend it to have domain $\overline{\{x_m\mid m\in \Bbb N\}}$, which is the closure of the image of the unit ball under $B$ (denote this map by $\overline{A\!S}$). You can again use the boundedness of $S_n$ to get that $AS_{n_k} x\to \overline{A\!S}x$ for all $x$ in the image of the unit ball under $B$:
$$\|\overline{A\!S}x - AS_{n_k}x\| ≤ \|\overline{A\!S}(x-x_m)\|+\|\overline{A\!S}(x_m)- AS_{n_k}(x_m)\|+\|AS_{n_k}(x_m-x)\|$$
you may choose $x_m$ to make the first and the second terms as small as you like, the middle term converges to zero by the arguments before - hence for any $m$ you can find $K$ after which it is as small as you like.

Continue with arguments of this kind to get that $\overline{A\!S}$ is linear and then also itself Lipschitz - you may thus extend it to a continuous linear map $\overline{A\!S}:\overline{B(X)}\to X$. Whats left is to check that $AS_{n_k}B$ converges uniformly on bounded sets to $\overline{A\!S}B$ (ie in operator norm).

Supposing this were not the case you would get a sequence $y_k$ in the unit ball of $X$ with $\|(AS_{n_k}B-\overline{A\!S}B)y_k\|>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$. Well you know what to do: $B(y_k)$ has a convergent sub-sequence so just assume that $B(y_k)$ converges with limit $x$. But we have already done this calculation
$$\|(\overline{A\!S}-AS_{n_k})(By_k)\| ≤ \|\overline{A\!S}(B(y_k)-x)\|+\|(\overline{A\!S}-AS_{n_k})(x)\| +\|AS_{n_k} (B(y_k)-x)\|$$
Each term converges by the same arguments as before.

Answer (score 1):

In the special case of Hilbert spaces, there is a much simpler proof of this result based on the fact that every compact
operator is the limit of finite rank ones (this in fact characterizes the [Approximation Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property) for
Banach spaces).

Here is the proof:

If  $y\in X$  and $f\in  X'$,  consider the operator
$U_{f,y}\in \mathcal B(X)$
given by
$$
  U_{f,y}(x) = f(x)y, \quad \forall x\in  X.
  $$
Evidently $U_{f,y}$ has rank-one and it is easy to see that every rank-one operator is of this form.

In case $A=U_{f,y}$ and $B= U_{g,z}$ then
$$
  T_{AB}(S)(x) = ASBx =  $$$$ =
  f(SBx)y = f(S(g(x)z))y = $$$$ =
  f(Sz)g(x)y = f(Sz)U_{g, y}(x),
  $$
which is to say that   $T_{AB}(S) = f(Sz)U_{g, y}$.  So  the range of $T_{A,B}$ is the one-dimensional space
spanned by $U_{g, y}$, whence $T_{A,B}$ has rank-one.

If  $A$  and $B$ have finite rank, then both $A$ and $B$ may be writen as finite sums of rank-one operators, from where
it follows that $T_{A,B}$ has finite rank (actually this proves that $\text{rank}(T_{A, B})\leq  \text{rank}(A)\text{rank}(B)$).

Assuming that $X$ has the Approximation Property,  such as if $X$ is a Hilbert space,  then the given compact operators
$A$ and $B$ may be written as
$$
  A=\lim_{n\to\infty }A_n,  \quad \text{and}\quad   B=\lim_{n\to\infty }B_n,
  $$
where $A_n$ and $B_n$ have finite rank,  so it easily follows
that $T_{A, B}$ is the operator-norm limit of $T_{A_n, B_n}$,  hence proving that $T_{A, B}$ is compact.